# I am trying to write a program in VBA that when a document is open a message box will appear that asks for user input to continue.?

Tags: vba

In this box it will say what document was opened, the last version that you read of it, and the current up to date version of the document.  The documents are named differently and are separated by 3 factors: an example of this would be QRS-RTY-006.G.docm, where QRS-RTY- is the same for all the documents, 006.G is the portion where you tell what version is available that I need to use to identify the current and last read version, and the .docm stays the same for each document.

Current Code:

```
    Dim A As String
    Dim B As String = Name

    Dim C As String
    Dim D As String = Name

    A = Split(B, "_")(0)
    C = Split(D, "_")(1)

    MsgBox("You have opened " & A & " Revision " & C & " . The last revision you read was ___. The current revision is  ___. Would you like to compare? ", vbYesNo)
    If vbYes Then

    End If
```

Comment: Sorry to add a little more detail I want it to tell the difference using a search function.  So the newest documents are all stored on a separate drive so I would like the program to search that drive for QRS-RTY-006 and then tell me what comes after that in the text box.  I hope everything is clear please ask for further clarification if needed.

Comment: How would you manage to know the last version the user read??? And what do you mean a separate drive? The opened file is not in the same folder than other versions?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good start :

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

Dim dName As String, _
    dVersion As String, _
    mAnswer As Integer, _
    SrcFile As String, _
    PossFiles As String

dName = Left(ActiveDocument.Name, 7)
dVersion = Right(Left(ActiveDocument.Name, Len(ActiveDocument.Name) - 5), 5)

mAnswer = MsgBox("You have opened : " & dName & ", Revision : " & dVersion & "." & Chr(13) & _
        "The last revision you read was ___." & Chr(13) & _
        "The current revision is  " & dVersion & Chr(13) & _
        Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Would you like to compare? ", vbYesNo)

If mAnswer <> vbYes Then
    'vbNo : They don't want to compare
Else
    'vbYes : They want to compare
    scrFile = Dir(ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & dName & "*.docm")
    Do While scrFile <> ""
        PossFiles = PossFiles & Dir & Chr(13)
        scrFile = Dir
    Loop
    If PossFiles <> vbNullString Then
        MsgBox PossFiles
    Else
        MsgBox "No other files found"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```